# Mathematica doesn't evaluate/simplify arithmetic expression in its output

Tags: matrix, simplifying-expressions, arithmetic

I have two matrices, `A := {{1, 2, -4}, {2, -2, -2}, {-4, -2, 1}}` and `V := {{-2/3, 1/Sqrt[2], -1/(3 Sqrt[2])}, {-1/3, 0, (2 Sqrt[2])/3}, {2/3, 1/Sqrt[2], 1/(3 Sqrt[2])}}`. I was interested in whether `Transpose[V].A.V` was a diagonal matrix with `6, -3, -3`.

However the output I got is the following:

[image]

When I saw *that*, I immediately thought I calculated something wrong on paper, but on closer inspection, most of those numbers are a complicated way of writing 0 or -3! In fact, `Simplify[%]` gives the expected format, and `Transpose[V].A.V == DiagonalMatrix[{6, -3, -3}]` is `True`.

Usually such mere numerical expressions are evaluated/simplified, why weren't they now?

Comment: See a simpler example in the help to Dot. I think that behavior is intended. It does not make great inconvenience for users.

Comment: A simpler example: `Sqrt[2] - 1/Sqrt[2]` is returned unmodified, and a simplification gives `1/Sqrt[2]`. Only a restricted set of ultrafast simplifications is done automatically: for example, `2+3` is auto-simplified to `5`. The system designer (WR) has to draw the line somewhere and leave more complex simplifications to the explicit invocation of `Simplify` or even `FullSimplify`. Apparently the line is drawn in a way that does not simplify/merge square roots by default. Maybe as computers get more powerful, the line will shift.

Comment: @Roman post as answer please. I was looking for an explanation/confirmation, I know how to call simplify myself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simpler example:

```
Sqrt[2] - 1/Sqrt[2]
(*    -(1/Sqrt[2]) + Sqrt[2]    *)
```

is returned unmodified, and a simplification gives

```
Simplify[%]
(*    1/Sqrt[2]    *)
```

Only a restricted set of ultrafast simplifications is done automatically: for example, `2 + 3` is auto-simplified to `5`. The system designer (WR) has to draw the line somewhere and leave more complex simplifications to the explicit invocation of `Simplify` or even `FullSimplify`. Apparently the line is drawn in a way that does not simplify/merge square roots by default. Maybe as computers get more powerful, the line will shift.

Answer (score 1):

```
Transpose[V].A.V // FullSimplify
(*{{6, 0, 0}, {0, -3, 0}, {0, 0, -3}}*)
```